Pnpm turbo repo command failed with exit code 3221225781.Error while loading shared libraries
I can't run my turbo repo in development mode due to this error.
I tried changing node and pnpm version according to my project package.json file and ensured they are compatible with each other but no use.I also tried to verify my node installation is correct or not by running js programs and importing and using built in packages but they worked correctly

I solved it after wasting a couples of hours.The problem was with my node.js installation,even though the js files were running fine on node there were some issue in its installation so i uninstalled it and then installed it again.This worked for me
